# The correspondence between complex differentiability and real differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

I have seen that a function $f: A\to \Bbb R^2$, $A \subseteq \Bbb R^2$, is (real) differentiable at a point $a \in A$ if both partial derivatives (of components) of $f$ exists at $a$ and one of them is continuous at $a$. Further, the corresponding complex function $f: A\to \Bbb C$ is differentiable if $f$ is real differentiable and satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Anything misled here? Infact, one can conclude that the continuity of atleast one partial derivative of $\operatorname{Re}f$ and $\operatorname{Im}f$ in conjunction with Cauchy-Riemann equations is enough for the complex differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

For a function of type $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the difference quotient:
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
describes the derivative of $f$, provided this expression exists (and is finite) for arbitrary $x$. 
*Since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are complete as a metric spaces, we don't have to worry about these expressions possibly converging to a hole in the space, so let's ignore completeness.*
The issue is **well-definition (w.r.t. $h$)**. That is, for any two different paths to zero (effectively sequences), we want the limiting expression to be the same. For the real case, continuity is enough because continuous functions preserve limits of sequences (hence two sequences converging to $x$ will have function values converging to $f(x)$).

---

For functions of type $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$, we have a difference quotient we can write down for each variable. Existence of each of these expressions requires *continuity (in each variable separately)*. 
For functions of type $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, we have a single difference quotient possible, that amounts to a difference quotient in each component function (appealing to direct product vector space structure of the image). Existence of this expression requires *continuity of all the component functions*.
For type $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, we have a difference quotient possible for each variable, which amounts to a collection of vectors of difference quotients as in the previous case. Existence of each of these expressions requires *continuity in all of the component functions (in each variable separately)*.

---

With this in mind, saying a function of type $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable is a little ambiguous (the reader would assume simply that all the expressions for the partials exist). We have no reason to assume the extra continuity condition?

---

Let's turn to type $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. Writing down the difference quotient:
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h},$$
we consider the same issue of well-definition. Surely continuity in the complex variable would work (since then limits are preserved etc.) But when we identify $f$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, we can only say whether the partial expressions exist for the component functions (recall what this requires). It does not give us well-definition immediately, since even:
$$\lim\limits_{(h^1,h^2)\to (0,0)}\frac{\bigg(Re\big(f(z^1+h^1,z^2+h^2)\big)-Re\big(f(z^1,z^2)\big),Im\big(f(z^1+h^1,z^2+h^2)\big) - Im\big(f(z^1,z^2)\big)\bigg)}{(h^1,h^2)}$$
suggests a path discrepancy for sequences $\{(h^1_n,h^2_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where say $h^1_n \equiv 0$ or $h^2_n\equiv 0$. This is where Cauchy and Riemann come in and assert equality of both of these cases (when they exist). We should further argue that these perpendicular cases cover the rest of the possibilities of sequences converging to zero from other directions in the plane, for well-definition.

---

In summary, for complex differentiability, we need either: complex continuity or individual real and imaginary variable continuity of both Re(f) and Im(f), coupled with C-R equations (more succinctly: existence of both partials of $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$, satisfying C-R).
P.s. We can repeat all of this with the domain of $f$ being an *open set*. This further condition of being open is to avoid *one-sided derivatives*. But appropriate definitions can also be made there.

Comment: *"With this in mind, saying a function of type $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable is a little ambiguous (the reader would assume simply that all the expressions for the partials exist). We have no reason to assume the extra continuity condition?"* I don't see what's ambiguous about defining differentiability of multivariable functions. If the reader assumes that differentiability at a point means simply that partial derivatives exist at that point, then that's an error on the reader's part, not an ambiguity in the definition of differentiability.

Comment: Differentiability with respect to what?

Comment: google Frechet differentiability. Also known as 'total derivative'.

Comment: This aligns with existence of the Jacobian in the real case, the question remains, what is the necessity of the extra choice of continuous partial in OP statement?

Comment: It's not necessary to assume it; it's suffices to drop continuity of partials, and merely assume differentiability.